# KaTeX does not render HTML extension commands despite `strict: false` and `trust: true` options

Tags: katex

I'm trying to embed LaTeX expressions in the web documentation of my library.

That's the HTML code that `cargo`, Rust's build system, places into the head of HTML documents with documentation:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.15.1/dist/katex.min.css" integrity="sha384-R4558gYOUz8mP9YWpZJjofhk+zx0AS11p36HnD2ZKj/6JR5z27gSSULCNHIRReVs" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.15.1/dist/katex.min.js" integrity="sha384-z1fJDqw8ZApjGO3/unPWUPsIymfsJmyrDVWC8Tv/a1HeOtGmkwNd/7xUS0Xcnvsx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.15.1/dist/contrib/auto-render.min.js" integrity="sha384-+XBljXPPiv+OzfbB3cVmLHf4hdUFHlWNZN5spNQ7rmHTXpd7WvJum6fIACpNNfIR" crossorigin="anonymous" onload="renderMathInElement(document.body);"></script>
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        renderMathInElement(document.body, {
            strict: false,
            trust: true,
            delimiters: [
                {left: "$$", right: "$$", display: true},
                {left: "\\(", right: "\\)", display: false},
                {left: "$", right: "$", display: false},
                {left: "\\[", right: "\\]", display: true}
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

The `.tex` that is being embedded:

```tex
\begin{cases}
    \operatorname{try\_get\_len\_of\_closed\_int\_intvl\_from\_0}: \href{Self}{google.com} \rightharpoonup usize \\
    \operatorname{try\_get\_len\_of\_closed\_int\_intvl\_from\_0} = i \mapsto \lvert [0..i] \rvert
\end{cases}
```

Output:
[image]

How can I make KaTeX display the tex properly?

Comment: The question on GitHub of KaTeX https://github.com/KaTeX/KaTeX/discussions/3492

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the `onload` attribute that crept into the 3rd line in the the head of HTML document:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.15.1/dist/katex.min.css" integrity="sha384-R4558gYOUz8mP9YWpZJjofhk+zx0AS11p36HnD2ZKj/6JR5z27gSSULCNHIRReVs" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.15.1/dist/katex.min.js" integrity="sha384-z1fJDqw8ZApjGO3/unPWUPsIymfsJmyrDVWC8Tv/a1HeOtGmkwNd/7xUS0Xcnvsx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.15.1/dist/contrib/auto-render.min.js" integrity="sha384-+XBljXPPiv+OzfbB3cVmLHf4hdUFHlWNZN5spNQ7rmHTXpd7WvJum6fIACpNNfIR" crossorigin="anonymous" onload="renderMathInElement(document.body);"></script>
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        renderMathInElement(document.body, {
            strict: false,
            trust: true,
            delimiters: [
                {left: "$$", right: "$$", display: true},
                {left: "\\(", right: "\\)", display: false},
                {left: "$", right: "$", display: false},
                {left: "\\[", right: "\\]", display: true}
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

I.e. this line

```
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.15.1/dist/contrib/auto-render.min.js" integrity="sha384-+XBljXPPiv+OzfbB3cVmLHf4hdUFHlWNZN5spNQ7rmHTXpd7WvJum6fIACpNNfIR" crossorigin="anonymous" onload="renderMathInElement(document.body);"></script>
```

It caused the renderer to be called twice. And the first call happened with the default settings.